# Ошибка в bundle.js после сборки Webpack2

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Компиляция проходит успешно, но в консоле вижу эту ошибку:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще не понимаю с чем это может быть связано, причем, 
несколько дней работало потом вдруг перестало.

Comment: Вот мой конфиг Webpack2:
https://gist.github.com/merss19/95292b4336d10b2e6892ab63d6fc8fa7
https://gist.github.com/merss19/815d3ff60a1a475a426df8a76af384c7

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите текст ошибки в самом вопросе, важные части кода по указанным ссылкам также приведите в вопросе. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными. Обязательно ознакомьтесь со статьёй про [mcve].